# wp_postmeta are updated for only one page

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

Code below only updates `wp_postmeta` of one specific post, not all the posts. On other pages the `meta_key` is not even added to the table, so it is not the problem with saving but with something else, and I have no idea what. I've tried generating the meta field with a plugin, Advanced custom fields, but the situation is the same, only the same particular page gets updated, rest are not.

What could cause this selective updates?

```
function damad_add_post_metabox() {

$screens = array( 'post', 'page');

foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

add_meta_box(
    'damad_post_meta_id',
    __( 'Options', 'damad' ),
    'damad_inner_custom_box',
    $screen
);
}
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'damad_add_post_metabox' );

function damad_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'damad_inner_custom_box', 'damad_inner_custom_box_nonce' );

 $homepage = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_featured', true);
echo '<label for="post-featured">';
   _e("Include in homepage slider", 'damad');
echo "</label>";
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="post-featured" name="post-featured" value="post-featured"';
if ( 'post-featured' == $homepage ) {
echo 'checked="checked"';
} 
echo '/>';
}

function damad_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

if ( ! isset( $_POST['damad_inner_custom_box_nonce'] ) )
   return $post_id;

 $nonce = $_POST['damad_inner_custom_box_nonce'];

 if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'damad_inner_custom_box' ) )
    return $post_id;

 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return $post_id;

  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

   } else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;
  }

 $featureddata = $_POST['post-featured'];

  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_featured', $featureddata );
 }
 add_action( 'save_post', 'damad_save_postdata' );
```

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Please use same tabs or spaces. In this form that code is not readable.

Comment: The above code worked for me without making any changes to it. Can you please check as said by s_ha_dum?